# Titlesec shows in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec

I use `titlesec` to show the writer and translator of each chapter of my book as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\chapterauthor}{}
\newcommand{\chaptertranslator}{}

\titleformat{\chapter}% command to format the chapter titles
[hang]% shape/type of title
{\LARGE\bfseries}% formatting commands applied to both label and title
{\makebox[0.5in][l]{\thechapter}}% chapter number; here set inside an invisible box with a constant width
{0em}% separation between number and chapter title; we've already covered this with the box
{}% additional formatting command for title itself not applied to number
[% everything inside [...] below comes after the title
\hfill% 
\normalsize\normalfont% reset font formatting
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}% add a half-space of vertical space before author
\hspace*{0.5in}% indent author name width of chapter number box 
\begin{tabular}{rl} %
    Author: & \kern-0.5em\chapterauthor \\
    Translator: & \kern-0.5em\chaptertranslator\\
\end{tabular}%
]% end of what comes after title
\titlespacing*{\chapter}% spacing commands for chapter titles; the star unindents first line afterwards
{0em}% spacing to left of chapter title
{0ex}% vertical space before title 
{3\baselineskip}% vertical spacing after title; here set to 3 lines 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\chapterauthor}{Alphonse Lamartine}
\renewcommand{\chaptertranslator}{Ine}

\chapter{New chapter}
Here it is. 
\renewcommand{\chapterauthor}{Heinrich Böll}
\renewcommand{\chaptertranslator}{Llöb Chirnieh}
\chapter{Another chapter}
Here again.


\end{document}
```

At every chapter, I redefine the author and translator thus:

```
\renewcommand{\chapterauthor}{Heinrich Böll}
\renewcommand{\chaptertranslator}{Llöb Chirnieh}
```

The problem is that, this treats the table of contents as a chapter, and since there are no writers or translators of the Table of Contents, it shows a empty Author and Translator just above the ToC like this:

```
    Author:
Translator:
```

How should I prevent this?

===Edit: to show that `\boolfalse{withauthor}` in `Bernard`'s comment is not sufficient===

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{withauthor}

\newcommand{\chapterauthor}{}
\newcommand{\chaptertranslator}{}

\titleformat{\chapter}% command to format the chapter titles
[hang]% shape/type of title
{\LARGE\bfseries}% formatting commands applied to both label and title
{\makebox[0.5in][l]{\thechapter}}% chapter number; here set inside an invisible box with a constant width
{0em}% separation between number and chapter title; we've already covered this with the box
{}% additional formatting command for title itself not applied to number
[% everything inside [...] below comes after the title
\ifbool{withauthor}{\hfill% 
\normalsize\normalfont% reset font formatting
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}% add a half-space of vertical space before author
\hspace*{0.5in}% indent author name width of chapter number box 
\begin{tabular}{rl} %
    Author: & \kern-0.5em\chapterauthor \\
    Translator: & \kern-0.5em\chaptertranslator\\
\end{tabular}}{}%
\boolfalse{withauthor}
]% end of what comes after title
\titlespacing*{\chapter}% spacing commands for chapter titles; the star unindents first line afterwards
{0em}% spacing to left of chapter title
{0ex}% vertical space before title 
{3\baselineskip}% vertical spacing after title; here set to 3 lines 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\chapterauthor}{Alphonse Lamartine}
\renewcommand{\chaptertranslator}{Ine}
\booltrue{withauthor}
\chapter{New chapter}
Here it is.
%\renewcommand{\chapterauthor}{Heinrich Böll}
%\renewcommand{\chaptertranslator}{Llöb Chirnieh}
%\boolfalse{withauthor}
\chapter{Another chapter}
Here again.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have updated with a minimal working example. It should be compiled with `XeLaTeX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose all unnumbered chapters will have no author nor translator, and  all numbered chapters will.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{withauthor}

\newcommand{\chapterauthor}{}
\newcommand{\chaptertranslator}{}

\titleformat{\chapter}% command to format the chapter titles
[hang]% shape/type of title
{\LARGE\bfseries}% formatting commands applied to both label and title
{\makebox[0.5in][l]{\thechapter}}% chapter number; here set inside an invisible box with a constant width
{0em}% separation between number and chapter title; we've already covered this with the box
{}% additional formatting command for title itself not applied to number
[% everything inside [...] below comes after the title
\ifbool{withauthor}{\hfill%
\normalsize\normalfont% reset font formatting
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}% add a half-space of vertical space before author
\hspace*{0.5in}% indent author name width of chapter number box
\begin{tabular}{ll} %
    Author: & \kern-0.5em\chapterauthor \\
    Translator: & \kern-0.5em\chaptertranslator\\
\end{tabular}}{}%
\global\boolfalse{withauthor}
]% end of what comes after title
\titlespacing*{\chapter}% spacing commands for chapter titles; the star unindents first line afterwards
{0em}% spacing to left of chapter title
{0ex}% vertical space before title
{3\baselineskip}% vertical spacing after title; here set to 3 lines
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\chapterauthor}{Alphonse de Lamartine}
\renewcommand{\chaptertranslator}{Ine}
\booltrue{withauthor}
\chapter{New chapter}
Here it is.
%\renewcommand{\chapterauthor}{Heinrich Böll}
%\renewcommand{\chaptertranslator}{Llöb Chirnieh}
%\boolfalse{withauthor}
\chapter{Another chapter}
Here again.


\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `@Bernard`, the second one would be better. But doing this deletes all authors & translators for all chapters. How should I tell the chapter that it has an author?  If I want a numbered chapter not to have an author, how should I adapt it?

Comment: Writing before the chapter `\booltrue{withauthor}`. I added in the proposed code the line `\boolfalse{withauthor}`, to get back to the default at the end.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, it works. But the `\boolfalse{withauthor}`  does not automatically delete the author in the next chapters, so one has to write it before every chapter one or another of these, it seems.

Comment: Strange… Could you post a minimal example that we could play with?

Comment: I cannot post it in a comment, where should I post it?

Comment: Can't you add it to your original post?

Comment: Done! Please check.

Comment: @usr203050: It was enough to add `\global` before `\boolfalde{withauthor}`. See my updated answer, with your minimal example. I took the liberty to change the alignment of the first column: left aligned looks better in this case, in my opinion.

Comment: `@Bernard`, very good! Thank you. I have modified it accordingly.